# Reuse less variable passed as an argument for parametric mixins

Tags: css, variables, less

Is it possible to use a less variable as an argument for parametric mixins?

Here's an example:

```
@red: #ff0000;
@blue: #0000ff;

.body-theme(@color){
   background: @color;
   p {
       color: @color;
   }      
}

body{
    &.red{
        .body-theme(@red);
    }
    &.blue{
        .body-theme(@blue);
    }
}
```

This example isn't really clever but it should illustrate that I want to reuse a part of the css with the option to only set the color as the parameter.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://lesscss.org/features/ Here it does allow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, test it out: http://lesstester.com/ trying your example out here shows that it will work, giving this output:

```
body.red {
  background: #ff0000;
}
body.red p {
  color: #ff0000;
}
body.blue {
  background: #0000ff;
}
body.blue p {
  color: #0000ff;
}
```

You should use this in the future to quickly test, if you are unsure if something can be done in less or not.